Stuck while installing NPM in Windows64 architecture (Not able to see NPM --version)
After installing Node i am able to see Node -version but not able to see NPM -version and also npx version getting error like('CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
9.6.3)
also tried to uninstall node js and installed again and also cleared all the npm folder from the system and reinstalled Node again but still issue did't resolved window64 is the architecture of my system
After installing Node i am able to see Node -version but not able to see NPM -version and also npx version getting error like('CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
9.6.3)
also tried to uninstall node js and installed again and also cleared all the npm folder from the system and reinstalled Node again but still issue did't resolved window64 is the architecture of my system
also tried to set environment variables too but still not able to install npm
also tried (Not able to use npm in WIndows)
Expecting NPM need to be installed in my system
